# Using 2 different WebView2 with the same CoreWebView2Environment

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-edge, webview2

I have an Excel VSTO add-in that uses WebView2 components into its panels.
[WebView2 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1185.39)

**I am trying to display two WebView2 using the same CoreWebView2Environment object, so I can set it up at launch without having to manage several folders.**
At runtime, both webviews are initialized however only one shows up correctly. The other loads an incomplete version of itself without any error raised in C# or the web console.

I am creating the environment folder on add-in start-up:

```
public static async void CreateEnvironmentDirectory()
{
    string userDataStorage = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), MY_APP_FOLDER);
    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new("--disk-cache-size=1 ");
    
    MyCoreWebView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(default, userDataStorage, options);
}
```

Then, when the panel is loading:

```
private async Task InitializeWebviews()
{
    await InitializeWebview(MyFirstWebview, myFirstUrl);
    await InitializeWebview(MySecondWebview, mySecondUrl);
}
private async Task InitializeWebview(WebView2 webview, string url)
{
    await webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(WebView2Manager.MyCoreWebView2Environment);
    webview.Navigate(url);
}
```

After tweaking around for a bit I discovered I could make it work by throwing a Thread.Sleep(500) in between both initialisations. It works on debug build only though.
For obvious reasons this is not the kind of solution I'm looking for, and I'm out of clean ideas to have it run properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to create TWO instances of the `CoreWebView2Environment` class with the same settings?

Comment: How is it related to VSTO? Do you get the same picture with a regular windows forms application?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I realize it doesn't relate to VSTO, I just put the tag because it is in a VSTO project, I might as well remove it if it doesn't suit the subject.

Comment: @PoulBak thank you for the idea. I have tried implementing your suggestion however I observe that when reloading the panel several times, it ends up with the same behavior I have described in the original post. If I keep reloading the panel, Excel shuts down. I will try to check if my implementation is at fault and will edit if needed.

Comment: I test with code [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYEtF.png) and it can load the two WebView2 successfully. You can refer to it. But mine is a simple WinForms project. You can also try if it works well in simple WinForms project without Excel VSTO. If so, I think it might be related with VSTO project.